# How can a traveller to Namibia best support African businesses?

Tags: namibia, ethical-travel

Namibia is a post-Apartheid nation and has been independent of South Africa for nearly 30 years.

However huge imbalances of wealth and ownership remain.

In Namibia, the tourist industry accounts for something like 15% of Namibia's GDP, and nearly 20% of employment. The industry is heavily based on land ownership - the places where tourists stay and spend their money tend to be on privately-owned land.

Namibia suffered centuries of colonial subjugation, including the forcible removal of native people from the land and much, much worse, followed by Apartheid. One legacy if this is that very visibly, the vast majority of the tourist industry is owned by white people with European names, who employ black people (who serve mostly white tourists).

(In addition, historically, a large proportion of Namibia's GDP has left the country through the foreign ownership of industry, though I don't know to what extent this affects the tourist industry.)

What would be good ways for a foreign traveller in Namibia to help ensure as far as possible that the money they spend as tourists remains in the country, and that it supports businesses that are not just locally-owned, but also owned by historically disadvantaged segments of the population?

Comment: Why the downvotes people?

Comment: I would assume patronizing smaller vendors for arts and crafts and staying in standalone local hotels (some of which have excellent service) instead of international chains will go some ways to make you comfortable.

Comment: @JoErNanO I conjecture some people may be sensitive to any kind of political talk or questions that reinforce the truth that indigenous populations have been exploited by western colonizers. Can never really tell.

Comment: @JoErNanO indeed. I can think of a few reasons why someone would downvote this question, all of which I disagree with.  But maybe there's a reason I haven't thought of and would agree with.  In any event, a comment about the reason for a downvote could still help improve the question.  If as Honorary World Citizen suggests it is distaste for political talk, the question could be reworded as "some people think ... how could those people ...?"  But there's little point in doing that if that isn't in fact the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but only the last paragraph seems relevant to the question. One's personal reasons for wanting to support local industry and initiatives and disadvantaged groups is ... well this is not the place.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I don't believe I disclosed any personal reasons or feelings. I described a situation, and asked how one could achieve a certain aim given that situation.

Comment: @DanieleProcida - It sounds preachy. As mentioned I didn't downvote and I wouldn't have, but it totally sounds preachy, off-topic, and irrelevant. The question of "how do I support local businesses and minorities and groups adversely affected by conflict XYZ" is entirely on-topic; the many paragraphs of off-topic dissertation as to why you want to do this has no impact on any potential answer. If I were you, I would open a discussion on Meta about this, since it is clearly not something we should be speaking of at length in the comments.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm not advocating that anyone else do anything, and I am not passing judgement on anyone who does or doesn't. I am only asking how someone who is interested in achieving a particular aim might be able to achieve it. I haven't said a single thing about *why*. If you feel it sounds "preachy" that's entirely up to you and I can't help you with it, but I think possibly it reflects more on your own feelings and judgements than you realise, and it's not my problem.

Comment: Look, I don't care one way or another. I was merely answering the question of "why downvotes", by pointing out that people come here to ask travel question. "How do I support local industry when visiting Namibia?" is a fine question. A post that's 90% preaching about historical injustices is pretty much a waste of time. There are 200 words in your post; the first 151 aren't important to the question. There's a reason "tl;dr" is a "thing" in the internet era. This is my point. I am now exiting the conversation.

Comment: While I am not yet ready to close or delete this question or do a serious edit, I feel it would be a much better question if a lot of the historical information is  contracted to a single line (like 'suffered for centuries'). As it stands it is very much a rant and not so much a question people are ready to answer.